# How to close a form that opened another form using ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, hide, show-hide, showdialog

so i have this `frmUser` but to close this i have to call `frmPass` (which i called using `ShowDialog()`instead of `Show()`) that will confirm first if the user is an admin but the problem is when i execute the codes below

```
frmUser us = new frmUser(lblEID.Text, lblAdmin.Text, lblType.Text);
us.Hide();
this.Hide();
```

`frmPass` only hides itself and not along with `frmUser`. Also here's my code calling `frmPass` from `frmUser`

```
frmPass pass = new frmPass(lblAID.Text, lblName.Text, lblType.Text, "User Module");
pass.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: it is not clear where the code is situated. where is the first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your password form, you should set `DialogResult` property of that form. In example; on your `frmPass`, when user clicks on button Ok, your code checks if username and password are valid. If everything is ok set dialog result as OK, like this:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;
}
```

that will close form. 
In `frmUser` you can, if needed, check what is `DialogResult` of `frmPass` form, like this:

```
frmPass pass = new frmPass(lblAID.Text, lblName.Text, lblType.Text, "User Module");
DialogResult dr = pass.ShowDialog();

if (dr == DialogResult.Ok)
{
    //do code if form is closed with OK dialog result
}
else
{
    // some warning to user...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to hide the wrong instace of `frmUser`. I assume that the first code passage is inside the class `frmPass`. There you create a new instance which you try to hide. But you want to hide the original instance.

As Nino already suggested I also would suggest to use the `DialogResult` to check whether the admin is confirmed. But may be you have already a different mechanism. Nevertheless you need to place the hiding code line into the class `frmUser` after the call of `pass.ShowDialog();`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formPass pass = new formPass();
    pass.ShowDialog();

    if(AdminIsConfirmed)
    {
         this.Hide();
    }
}
```

leave the other `this.Hide()` in the `frmPass` to close that.

**EDIT**

Another possibility would be to pass the `frmUser` instance into the constructor of `frmPass` and have a variable of type `frmUser` in `frmPass`. You just have to overload it :

```
public partial class formPass : Form
{
    formUser us;
    public formPass(/* all that stuff that you have plus*/, formUser us)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.us = us;
    }
```

call `frmPass` like this now:

```
frmPass pass = new frmPass(lblAID.Text, lblName.Text, lblType.Text, "User Module", this);
```

now you can just remove the line:

```
frmUser us = new frmUser(lblEID.Text, lblAdmin.Text, lblType.Text);
```

and the whole thing will work and hide properly.